# why does all other values update while i used useEffect() on just 'time'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect, dayjs

The gap variable should just give a difference once, but it gives a diff every second. I am not even updating its state. Even if i use `settime` in `useEffect` still the other variable that are changing in background are still effecting the page and are updating.

```
const ftime = dayjs('Dec 31,2021').unix();
const dateVar = dayjs().unix();
const gap = ftime - dateVar;

const [time, settime] = useState(dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => settime(dayjs().second()), 1000);
}, []);

return (
  <div className="App">
    <div>{time}</div>
    <div>{gap}</div>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
 setInterval(() => settime(dayjs().second()), 1000)
}, [])
```

`settime` is invoked for every 1000ms. This will update the state (`time`) and trigger a rerender.

```
 const ftime = dayjs('Dec 31,2021').unix();
 const dateVar = dayjs().unix();
 const gap = ftime - dateVar;
```

As these three variables are initialised at the top level of the function, the rerender will initialise them every time.

If you want to prevent this, you can move the variables outside the function component.

Answer (score 0):

It is updating every second because you change `time` every second, which the component renders.

This rerendering will also cause the constants `ftime` and `dateVar` to reinitialise every second. If this is not intended, you need to put them outside the function or wrap them in a hook, such as `useState` or `useMemo`.

You can solve the rerendering issue by making the time a React component and placing the interval effect in that component. A child's rerendering normally doesn't trigger a rerender in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in `useEffect` you are updating the state every second. When a state updates in a react function component the variables will be re-initialized and react doesn't track the values of the variables. It only keeps track on state and props.

Here you can make use of `useRef` hook since its is mutable and react does not re-initialize its value, which guarantees its value to be same during state update

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const gap = useRef(dayjs("Dec 31,2021").unix() - dayjs().unix());

  const [time, settime] = useState(dayjs().format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => settime(dayjs().second()), 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div> {time}</div>
      **<div>{gap.current}</div>**
    </div>
  );
}
```